# How do I solve the problem with reduce function in R

Tags: r

It used to work when I run

```
v1 <- lapply(list.files(pattern = glob2rx('xxxx.csv')), function(i){read.csv(i, header = TRUE)}) %>% reduce(full_join)
```

However, the error occurred recently

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reduce’ for signature ‘"list"’

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `reduce` from `purrr` ? Try with `purrr::reduce`.

Comment: It works when I tried `purrr::reduce`, thanks for pointing it out! Although I am still confused about why the code ran smoothly without placing `purrr::` before `reduce` last time.

Comment: You loaded a package that masks `purrr::reduce`.

Comment: This could be the reason.